# Keeping multiple sound files ready in MediaPlayer (like in a SounPool)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, soundpool

My app currently uses a `SoundPool` to manage all the different sounds. When the user taps the button, a sound should play. Since he might push that button quite quickly, the sounds should be able to play on top of each other.
The `SoundPool` is not able to listen for a sound finishing nor can it get the length of a sound file. Therefore I am thinking about using the `MediaPlayer`.
I have no experience with the `MediaPlayer`, but it seems that it is not as straight forward to set up that ability to quickly play a sound. Unfortunately I have to check when a sound finished playing, so I will have to rewrite using the `MediaPlayer`.

How would you make the `MediaPlayer` able to play many short sounds?

Answer (score 0):

an instance of a media player plays one sound at a time. it's better to use soundpool..

try this with soundpool...

1) create an int, don't leave it null. somewhere before the onCreate method.

2) in the onCreate method attach a resource to it

3) lastly, apply logic to a button..

```
    int db1, db2, db3, db4, db5 = 0;

    db1 = sp.load(this, R.raw.snd1, 1);
    db2 = sp.load(this, R.raw.snd2, 1);
    db3 = sp.load(this, R.raw.snd3, 1);
    db4 = sp.load(this, R.raw.snd4, 1);
    db5 = sp.load(this, R.raw.snd5, 1);

    samplebutton5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             if (db5 != 0)
              sp.play(db5, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);


        }
    });
```

Comment: The problem is not with using `SoundPool`. I already managed to do so. My problem is, that `SoundPool` can not listen for a sound to stop playing nor get the length of the sound. I will therefore have to use `MediaPool`. - I clarified this in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

To use soundpool if you like you can first get the sound length by using MediaPlayer by using the following method:

```
private long getSoundDuration(int rawId)
{
    MediaPlayer player =  MediaPlayer.create(activity, rawId);
    int duration = player.getDuration();
    player.release();
    return duration;
}
```

And afterwards use an handler and write something like:

```
handler.postAtTime(this, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + duration);
```

The handler will wait until sound is finished to do the next task whatever that may be.